# How to get uploaded file's path?

Tags: django, django-models, supabase

When I upload file through admin dashboard in Django dev server, I always get error that file doesnt exist. With that it is pointing in local folder and searching for <file_name> I want to upload it to supabase but Django isn't finding the file which i Choose in /admin

This is my code:

```
class PupinObject(models.Model):
    video = forms.FileField(upload_to='videos/')
    creation_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(PupinUser, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        url = os.environ.get("SUPABASE_URL")
        key = os.environ.get("SUPABASE_KEY")
        supabase = create_client(url, key)

        bucket_name = "videos"
        new_file = self.video.path

        print(default_storage.path(self.video.name))


        jwt = supabase.auth.sign_in_with_password({ "email": self.user.email, "password": self.user.password })

        # Upload the file to the user's directory
        supabase.storage.from_(bucket_name).upload(f"/{jwt.user.id}/video.mp4", new_file)

        super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

I tried getting absolute path but no light.

Comment: What do you mean with "not light"?

Comment: Try changing `new_file = self.video.path` to `new_file = self.video.url`.

Comment: "no light" like no hope ahah... 

@raphael Didn't work. It constantly tries to read from local path so I will leave it without upload_to in model. I will read it from supabase with slug, rather than url I wanted to store right after saving new object. Thanks anyway.